# How can I build a Debian package for Eric 6.1.9?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, eric

The latest version of Eric in the official Xenial repositories is 6.0.8 and I'd like to install 6.1.9. I know I could get the source and run `sudo python3 install.py` from the extracted source directory, to install the latest Eric. The problem, is that I'd like my new Eric installation be registered with dpkg. I know how to build a Debian package for programs who's source directories have a Makefile in them (i.e., using `checkinstall`), but Eric's source directory consists of the following files (revealed by running `ls` from said directory):

```
changelog        eric                     install.py          __pycache__      THANKS
description-pak  eric6config.py           LICENSE.GPL3        README-i18n.rst  uninstall-debugclients.py
doc-pak          install-debugclients.py  patch_modpython.py  README.rst       uninstall.py
```

Comment: Why go through those hoops when you can get a debian installer for 6.1.8 : https://packages.debian.org/sid/eric ? Does that 0.0.1 matter?

Comment: Well that sounds like a reasonable temporary work-around, thanks. Although if anyone finds a simple method (like similar to checkinstall) to build an Eric package I would prefer that.